# SWT JFace: How to make TableViewer always selects a row?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I'm a new bee in JFace.

My table viewer alloc code is:

```
viewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL
| SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER);
```

And I have a TableCursor created to select different cells in a row.

[image: Select a row in the table]

Then I find out that it is quite embarrassing to allow the user "select nothing". :-(

[image: Select nothing in the table, very ugly right?]

I'm wondering if there is a SWT property to set or some coding solutions to force users always selecting a row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to supress the deselection manually, see the following snippet:

```
viewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {

    private boolean update;

    private ISelection lastSelection;

    @Override
    public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
        if (event.getSelection().isEmpty() && !update) {
            update = true;
            v.setSelection(lastSelection);
            update = false;
        } else if (!event.getSelection().isEmpty()) {
            lastSelection = event.getSelection();
        }

    }
});
```